# Can we use facebook "game service" for android non gaming applications?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-4.x

Can we use facebook "game service" for android non gaming applications ? I want to reward my users for sending app install invite, FB page invite request and post share from my android non gaming application(Native android app). Can someone point me to achieve these ? Are there any FB policy violations to achieve these for non gaming applications ? Also I want to know the number of invites sent i.e.,  just invites count.

Comment: You are not allowed to reward users for sending out invites or posting. The most you are allowed to reward users for, are _successful_ invites.

Comment: @CBroe **Successful invites** means once the user's friend/recipient accepts the invite, Am I correct ? If so, that's enough for my requirements. Could you please explain how to get the "successful invites"  list from my user (just invites count) ? / how to track it ?

Comment: The documentation has an explanation how that works for canvas apps, via HTTP. No idea how it works for a purely client-side Android app.